# How to stream a video on a node.js server to a video element on the browser

Tags: node.js, stream, blob

l am using streams in node `createReadStream(pathToVideoFile).pipe(res)`, l then create a video blob on the client side from the `res.data` string from the server followed by `URL.createObjectURL(videoFile)` and finally setting the video src and loading the video. The problem is the video player shows a loading spinner and disappears and no video is shown. This is a code snippet that convert the `res.data` string into a blob and sets it to play on the video element

```
const Video = (props) => {
    if(props.video !== '') {
        // File
        let videoFile = props.loading?new Blob([props.video], { type : "video\/mp4" }):props.video
    
        // Video element
        const videoElement = document.getElementById(`${props.loading?'video-element-loading':'video-element'}`)
    
        // Source element
        const source = document.getElementById(`${props.loading?'video-source-loading':'video-source'}`)
    
        // Create url to the video
        const videoSrc = URL.createObjectURL(videoFile)

        // Set src
        source.setAttribute("src", videoSrc)

        // Load video
        videoElement.load()

        // URL.revokeObjectURL(videoFile)
    }
}
 
export default Video
```

When l inspect network tab, the blob file has a size of 0MB but the response headers particularly the Content-Length header has a significant value greater than 0. How can l successifully stream the video on the browser